# Python- What colormap scheme should I use for exponential-ish data?

Tags: python, matplotlib, exponential, colormap

**The issue**

I have a plot I'm trying to make for trends of precipitation rates around the world using gridded data. I can make the plot itself fine, but the color range is giving me issues. I can't figure out how to make the colormap better fit my data, which seems exponential. **I tried a logarithmic range, but it doesn't quite fit the data right.**

**The code & data range**

Here's what my 8,192 data values look like when plotted in order on a simple x-y line plot. Data points are on the x-axis & values are on the y-axis.
[image]

Here's what my data looks like plotted with a LogNormal color range. It's too much mint green & orange-red for me.

```
#Set labels
lonlabels = ['0','45E','90E','135E','180','135W','90W','45W','0']
latlabels = ['90S','60S','30S','Eq.','30N','60N','90N']

#Set cmap properties
norm = colors.LogNorm() #creates logarithmic scale

#Create basemap
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15.,10.))
m = Basemap(projection='cyl',llcrnrlat=-90,urcrnrlat=90,llcrnrlon=0,urcrnrlon=360.,lon_0=180.,resolution='c')
m.drawcoastlines(linewidth=1)
m.drawcountries(linewidth=1)
m.drawparallels(np.arange(-90,90,30.),linewidth=0.3)
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180.,180.,45.),linewidth=0.3)   
meshlon,meshlat = np.meshgrid(lon,lat)
x,y = m(meshlon,meshlat)

#Plot variables
trend = m.pcolormesh(x,y,lintrends[:,:,0],cmap='jet', norm=norm, shading='gouraud')

#Set plot properties
#Colorbar
cbar=m.colorbar(trend, size='8%',location='bottom',pad=0.8) #Set colorbar
cbar.set_label(label='Linear Trend (mm/day/decade)',size=25) #Set label
for t in cbar.ax.get_xticklabels():
     t.set_fontsize(25) #Set tick label sizes
#Titles & labels
fig.suptitle('Linear Trends of Precipitation (CanESM2)',fontsize=40,x=0.51,y=0.965)
ax.set_title('a) 1979-2014 Minimum Trend',fontsize=35)
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0,405,45))
ax.set_xticklabels(lonlabels,fontsize=20)
ax.set_ylabel('Latitude',fontsize=25)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(-90,120,30))
ax.set_yticklabels(latlabels,fontsize=20)
```

[image]

And here's what it looks like with a default, unaltered color range. (Same code minus the norm=norm argument.)

[image]

**The question**

Is there a mathematical scheme I can use to create a colormap that better shows the range of my data? Or do I need to make a custom range?

Comment: So if it is the colors you don't like, you can choose a different colormap. Here is a list of possible colormaps. http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html. You might also want to check if the `PowerNorm`instead of the `LogNorm` is better for what you want to show.

Comment: It's not so much the colors themselves as it is the range. If I could get more blues, cyans, and yellows to show up on the map, I'd be happy.

Anyway, I played around with PowerNorm earlier and it didn't seem to work, but I just tried it again & after I set vmax = 3, now it looks more even, albeit a bit heavy on the dark blues for all the zero values. (Not much I can do about that.) Post this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: On a related note: [please do not use the jet colormap](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/223315/why-use-colormap-viridis-over-jet). Because the yellow part of the colormap is brighter than the red or blue parts, it draws attention to the median values of your array, which are the least interesting from a data visualization point of view. There are [plenty of more appropriate colormaps](http://matplotlib.org/users/colormaps.html) which will help your plots look better :).

Comment: A jet-like rainbow colormap is actually the standard in my field for depicting precipitation plots.

Comment: The other thing you can try is the SymLogNorm. Typically you use it when you need logarithmic scaling with positive and negative values, but it does also work when you want to split between a linear and logarithmic range.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and resolved it myself, so I'll answer here. What you really want is a nonlinear color scale. Functions like `imshow` can take a `norm`, which can scales the value-color relationship any which way, including nonlinearly. If you want the colors to be logarithmically scaled, that's a problem if 0 is a part of the domain, because it will try to map 0 to log(0) = -inf, which won't work. So you will have to add a small value to your data so that it's never 0. In literature sometimes you see log(1+x) plotted instead of x, so that's why, and that works. So you could plot 1+x, with logarithmic color scaling. Another solution is to not plot logarithmically, and instead plot via a power law, then you won't get issues with 0. So you can map the colors x to x^a with a < 1. This is fundamentally different, but unless you have fine detail at literally every scale (this is when you truly need logarithmic scaling), it should look fine.

So how do you do all this? Some matplotlib functions take a `norm`. You want `norm` to be some color scale, like `matplotlib.colors.LogNorm(1, 2)` for plotting 1+x with x between 0 and 1, or `matplotlib.colors.PowerNorm(.5)` for plotting x with sqrt(x) color scaling.

Answer (score -1):

## A hack

You could try applying a maximum value, i.e. for any value above 2 simply replace it with 2.

Then you would have a single color (the maximum) representing 2+ and the rest of the colors would be spread across your data more evenly.

Comment: I did do that eventually, but I also needed to switch my normalization to PowerNorm & play around with the scale.